# How does the independent events rule prove independence?

Tags: probability, independence

We are taught to find if events **A** and **B** are independent it will satisfy the equation          **P**(**A** and **B**) = **P**(**A**)**P**(**B**), but how does this prove independence.

Comment: That's the definition of independence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Event A being independent of event B denotes that p(A) is **unaffected** by whether event B has occurred.

WLOG assume that $p(A) \neq 0 \neq p(B).$

Event A is independent of event B denotes that 
$p(A) = p(A|B) \iff p(B) \times p(A) = p(B) \times p(A|B) = p(AB)$ 
by Bayes Theorem.